# .push to a sub-doc knowing _id of parent and a name:value of the sub-doc?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to push an update to an embedded doc, by finding the parent via the _id..

Am looking for the correct syntax for something like this, where the parent is found by _id and the sub-doc is found by the username field:

```
Models.Message.findById(req.params.message_id, { "to.username": "username1" } ).exec(function (err, message) {
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html mentions *"Each document has an _id. DocumentArrays have a special id method for looking up a document by its _id."*, but doesn't mention anything about looking up a sub-doc by a name:value

..the .find call is followed by:

```
    message.to.push({

        read :
        {
            marked : req.body.markedRead,
            datetime : req.body.datetimeRead
        },
        updated : req.body.nowDatetime

    }); // .push where "to.username": "username1" in UserMessageSchema [array]

    // save the message, and check for errors
    message.save(function(err) {

        if (err)
            res.send(err);

    res.json({ message: 'Message "' + req.params.message_id + '" MarkedRead for: username1' });

    });

}); // findByID of Message
```

Here's the db record:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53b185a687942abdfc234e2a"),
    "created" : ISODate("2014-06-30T15:43:34Z"),
    "message" : "Here's a Message",
    "to" : [
        {
            "user" : ObjectId("53aada6f8b10eb0000ec8a90"),
            "username" : "username1",
            "updated" : ISODate("2014-06-30T15:43:34Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("53b185a687942abdfc234e2b"),
            "read" : {
                "marked" : false
            }
        },
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Here's the correct codeset, thanks to @NielLunn's answer:

```
        Models.Message.findOneAndUpdate(

        { "_id": req.params.message_id, "to.username": "username1" },
        {
            "$set": { 
                "to.$.read.marked": req.body.markedRead,
                "to.$.read.datetime": req.body.datetimeRead,
                "to.$.updated": req.body.datetimeRead
            }
        }, // $set (change existing): to.$.. ($ identifies the matching index of the array to update, based on the query)

        function (err, message) {

                if (err)
                    res.send(err);

                res.json({ message: 'Message "' + req.params.message_id + '" MarkedRead for: username1' });

        }

        ); // findOneAndUpdate "to.username": "username1"

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could use [`.findOne()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) for this which accepts a full query rather than just the primary `_id` value which is what `.findById()` is essentially a helper for. But really, since you don't seem to need any other validation triggers you can just issue [`.findOneAndUpdate()][2]` instead of retrieving and using `.save()`:

```
Message.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "_id": req.params.message_id, "to.username": "username1" },
    {
        "$set": { 
            "to.$.read.marked": false,
            "to.$.read.datetime": req.body.datetimeRead
            "to.$.updated": req.body.nowDatetime
        }
    },
    function(err,message) {

       // contains the updated message document
    }
);
```

The usage there is [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) as you are not adding an additional array, you are just changing what is existing.

Also not the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator in there that identifies the matching index of the array to update, based on the query you issued.

Comment: many thanks, this looks great, but for some reason it either has yet to run, or it's not finding any docs..because nothing happens after the preceding console.log(req.params.message_id); Also, tested this with Model.Message..same thing though.. Any sugestions?

Comment: The same thing happens in the console when testing creating multiple new Messages in a row with a regular .post (.find + .save)

Comment: Testing in the mongo shell, grabbing the id and username from a sample doc..this returns null: db.messages.findOne( { "_id": "53b203c2cc3060000000eadc", "to.username": "username1" } );

Comment: @StackThis Mongoose should be auto-casting your `_id` values. What do you get with just the `_id`? Not not mention that your `_id` value here doe not match the sample document, so are you sure that document has the same "username" that you are testing for.

Comment: @StackThis Oh and "Mongo Shell" will not auto-cast for you. You need to wrap with `ObjectId()` in order to match the object id in the field.

Comment: Wrapped with ObjectId(), the mongo shell found the doc (just another sample doc).. Node still skips from the console.log(), over the findOneAndUpdate, and runs right to the function call that's required to access the particular page (this gets called frequently for the page access)

Comment: @StackThis add the code you are trying now to your question. Console log all your req params for the _id and the date values before findOneAndUpdate is called. That way we can see what is going on.

Comment: Added the test code to the question.. Even commenting out the .get and .delete calls for this route, to further isolate this .put, the console logs everything at the top, but the findOneAndUpdate has yet to run..

Comment: @StackThis Can you actually add the console log output for those params please. That was really what I was asking to see.

Comment: @StackThis I'm still thinking something is wrong with the types. Try hardcoding those values as strings to test

Comment: Good call.. Had just done that.. Works now! Beyond grateful as always

Comment: res.locals.user data issue.. Now resolved.. Really appreciate the walkthrough

Answer (score 0):

Use [Model.update](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) plus [Mongodb Positional Operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

```
var query = {
  _id: req.params.message_id,
  "to.username": "username1"
}
var update_query ={
  $set:{
    "to.$.read":{
      marked : req.body.markedRead,
      datetime : req.body.datetimeRead
    },
    "to.$.updated" : req.body.nowDatetime
  }
}
Models.Message.update(query, update_query).exec(function (err, numAffected) {
  //Here you should check that err is null and numAffected is 1.
})
```